# Available space differs between sys.database_files and database properties dialog in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am looking at this for a few minutes now and could not find a thread mentioning this.

I wanted to query currently used space and available space from a database on SQL Server.
The numbers I query should match the numbers I see, when I open the properties dialog on a database in SQL Server Management Studio, like this:

[image: sample database properties showing Size: 17689,00MB and Space Available: 16795,77MB]

So I browsed a bit and found that I can query against `sys.database_files` like so (from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1629/determine-free-space-consumed-space-and-total-space-allocated-for-sql-server-databases/)):

```
SELECT
        DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
        name AS FileName, 
        size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB, 
        size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
    FROM sys.database_files;
```

This gets me this result:

```
DbName       FileName         CurrentSizeMB   FreeSpaceMB
databasename databasename     17338.000000    16795.312500
databasename databasename_log   351.000000      331.234375
```

Trying to recognize my numbers from the previous dialog:

- OK, adding `17338`and `351` gets me to `17689` which is exactly the size the dialog lists
- But for available space I cannot find it, `16795.312500` is off by almost half a MB

**What can I do to get exactly the same number the properties dialog shows for Space Available?**

Did I use the query/formulae in a wrong way or is this simply not possible at this point due to some rounding (converting pages/extents to MB...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Tracing the query used by ssms

*One way to do this is by taking the profiler's 'tuning' template and then tracing your login*

**This query pops up**

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize],
(SUM(a.total_pages) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(df.size as bigint)), 0) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type = 2 )) AS [SpaceUsed]
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id left join sys.internal_tables it on p.object_id = it.object_id
```

The query gets a `DbSize` and  `SpaceUsed` column from some DMV's.

**The `DbSize` column**

A straightforward query, get the size where the file type

- `= 0 = Rows`
- `= 2 = FILESTREAM`
- `= 4 = Full-text`

This query gets all file sizes except the log size.

I'm assuming this is added later as it is added to the total size in the properties pane.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize]
```

**The `SpaceUsed` column**

A bit bigger, first get the sum of total pages from the  `sys.allocation_units` `DMV`

```
...SUM(a.total_pages) + ... 
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id
...
```

And then add any filestream data to this number (if none then add `0` ):

```
...(SUM(a.total_pages) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(df.size as bigint)), 0) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type = 2 )
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id ...
```

**The total query**

Running the total query gives me:

```
DbSize  SpaceUsed
2557952 886791
```

Both the `DBSize` and `SpaceUsed` column is the size in `8KB` pages.

> What can I do to get exactly the same number the properties dialog
>   shows for Space Available?

**If I transform the query to be divided by `/128.0` and subtract `SpaceUsed` from `DBSize` like your query**

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) )/ 128.0 -
(SUM(a.total_pages) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(df.size as bigint)), 0) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type = 2 ))/ 128.0 AS [FreeSpace]
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id left join sys.internal_tables it on p.object_id = it.object_id
```

I can replicate the properties view of the space available:

```
FreeSpace
13055,945313
```

[image]

*Still need to apply rounding with 2 digits after the comma*

where your query gives me a lower amount on my database

```
FreeSpaceMB
13055.687500
```

---

### Trying to find a why

**Assumptions**

We established that the `DBSize` column is the same for both queries, the difference should be between the `total_pages` column from the `sys.allocation_units` dmv and the `FILEPROPERTY` function

```
FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT).
```

on the `FILEPROPERTY` documentation:

> Number of pages allocated in the file

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fileproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Where `total_pages` =

> Total number of pages allocated or reserved by this allocation unit.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Guess**

We are getting the sum of all these allocation units. My guess would be that the difference is based on the file having more overhead pages not directly in the allocation units dmv, such as File header, `PFS`, `GAM`, `SGAM`, `DCM`, `BCM`.

More on these [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

**Using `sp_spaceused` and `@updateusage` to update the space usage info (`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`)**

```
exec sp_spaceused
```

The `sp_spaceused` procedure gives the same result as the `SSMS` Properties window and the `sys.allocation_units` query.

```
unallocated space
13055.95 MB
```

But when running sp_spaceused with `@updateusage = 'true'`

> Indicates DBCC UPDATEUSAGE should be run to update space usage
>   information. When objname is not specified, the statement is run on
>   the whole database;
>   [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
EXEC sys.sp_spaceused  @updateusage = 'true';
```

The values are updated:

```
unallocated space
13056.07 MB
```

The changed SSMS query that uses `sys.allocation_units` also shows this updated value:

```
FreeSpace
13056,070313
```

While the `FILEPROPERTY` query did not change!

```
SELECT         size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
    FROM sys.database_files; 

FreeSpaceMB
13055.687500
```

Comment: Curious though that most threads (that I found) did never even mention the way to do it with allocation units, which seems to be the only valid way to get numbers consistent with SSMS.

Comment: Yes, of course. Use the Profiler to see what SSMS does, it's so ovious now :)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Haha yes I like to use that part. The exact why I am going to not be able to answer unfortunately. Maybe somebody else will.  I have also mostly seen `FILEPROPERTY`being used rather than `allocation_units`

Comment: one final comment: In the space used query I ommitted the `WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 )` to sum up all files, that way I get both numbers exactly as in the properties dialog: https://pastebin.com/AB57RVsy

Comment: @DrCopyPaste When using `@updateusage` on the `sp_spaceused` procedure, I do get new values for the ssms query while having the same for the query that uses the `FILEPROPERTY` function. Added it to the answer